How to display the image obtained from MusicInfo?
I am making a mobile application that is a music player but when I want to display the image in  it does not load. At the moment of using getMusicInfoAsync from MusicInfo, it returned the data correctly, but it is not displayed.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import Entypo from '@expo/vector-icons/Entypo';
import color from "../../misc/color";
import MusicInfo from "expo-music-info-2";

const AudioListItem = ({ title, duration, uri }) => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadAssets() {
            const metadata = await MusicInfo.getMusicInfoAsync(uri, {
                picture: true
            })//It does return the data correctly
            setImage(metadata.picture.pictureData)
        }
        loadAssets()
    }, [])
    return <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
            <View style={styles.thumbnail}>
                <Image style={styles.thumbnailImage} source={image/*Not load here*/} /> 
            </View>
            <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.timeText}>{duration}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
            <Entypo name="dots-three-vertical" size={20} color={color.font_medium} />
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
}

